# Cannot access web server created by Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, windows-10

For Windows 10 machine, I am following docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#explore-the-application-and-run-examples) to create local web server.

I run following command;

```
docker run -d -p 8086:8086 --name webserver nginx
```

and

```
docker inspect webserver
```

this gives me output like;

```
"Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "49caf62d4fee8e10aab2f43dbe0817e50efd6a647044f5e9d7ec674bbbe6f852",
                    "EndpointID": "0352ee7fe9d414748840f9b8c18784293ec15f25a2e0de8cbe7ee5a255cf57ae",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
```

so when i try to access http://172.17.0.3:8086 I cannot access to web server.

also I have output of `docker ps` as follows:

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `-p 8086:8086`, you are telling docker that you want to take port `8086` from inside the container and publish it to port `8086` on your host machine. However, there is nothing at port `8086` in your container. Ngix is running on port `80`. The command you want to use is:

```
docker run -d -p 8086:80 --name webserver nginx
```

This will map port `80` in your container to `8086` on your host machine. You should now be able to send it HTTP requests at `localhost:8086` from your host machine.

Answer (score 1):

**docker ps** command is showing the port number as **80** and you are exporting port number **8086**, why?

also try to use **localhost:8086** from the browser.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my SS. I took wrong one. I am still getting same error.